# How .sort() works on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to **sort** on **mongoose** using the .sort() method

`GET /api/v1/tours?sort=price`

```
let query = await Tour.find(queryStr);

if (req.query.sort) {
    const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
    query = query.sort(sort);
}

const tours = await query;
```

I am expecting to get a response based on the query parameter. But this is what i got instead:

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "message": "The comparison function must be either a function or undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object into the `sort()` method to determine a specific sort order like so:

```js
GET /api/v1/tours?sort=price&order=asc

const tours = await Tour.find(queryStr).sort({ 
   req.query.sort: req.query.order 
});
// .sort({ price: 'asc' });
// Sort by price ascending order


GET /api/v1/tours?sort=price&order=desc

const tours = await Tour.find(queryStr).sort({ 
   req.query.sort: req.query.order 
});
// .sort({ price: 'desc'});
// Sort by price descending order
```

You can use `asc`, `desc`, `ascending`, `descending`, `1`, and `-1` for the sort order values in the object.